# Passing HTML content through jQuery AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to display the content of Division in one page to another.

```
<div id="box-cont" class="box-content">                                                                 
  <?php
    echo $stat;// Contains multiple images with strings                                                                     
  ?>
</div>
```

Here **$stat** will display multiple images with few contents. And i am using jQuery AJAX to display this **html** in another page.

```
var bcont = $('#box-cont').html();
$.ajax({
   type:"POST", 
   url:"abc.php",   
   success: function(data) {
      document.location.href='def.php?bcont='+bcont;
   }
});
```

And i am getting this **html** in **def.php** as

```
$_GET['bcont'];
```

This is not working for me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you are passing whole html in url

Comment: i have tried using POST, wrapping the div inside <form> and method="POST". this is also not working :(

Comment: Do u have brief code of writing this in POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shortcut method would be to use sessions to pass the html from one page to another.

```
<div id="box-cont" class="box-content">                                                                 
  <?php
    echo $stat;
    $_SESSION['stat'] = $stat; // make sure session_start(); is present on this page
  ?>
</div>
```

Then, in the `success` handler of your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST", 
   url:"abc.php",   
   success: function(data) {
      window.location.href='def.php';
   }
});
```

Finally, in `def.php`

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['stat'];
```

Note: This is not an ideal approach but will do the job for you

Comment: Good quick fix, however (as implied by "not ideal approach"), saving html in session-data kind of itches...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you want to pass the html of #box-cont to def.php, right?

1. You're mixing post and get. Read: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
   and you'll find you need to use the data-parameter.
2. There's something odd with the success-part. You don't reload the frame/div
   where def.php is sitting. What you've done is passing data to the server
   but not getting anything back, (if I read your attempts correctly).
3. In fact there's currently little use for a server-via here, from what you
   describe it can all be done at client / JS.

Comment: But i have used $_POST[] in def.php to get the contents. and wrapping the div inside <form> and method="POST". that din worked..

Comment: In your post you write: "i'm getting this html...$_GET[]". Is that a typo? (POST is the way to go for this type of data)